# Git commands not working due to dubious ownership in the repository

Tags: linux, bash, git, chown

I changed my operating system to Linux Mint. In doing that I migrated local git repositories data to an external drive and then moved back the files again into the new OS. Now when I try to perform any git command onto those git repos I get an error :

fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII Semester/Major-2/Applify'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '/home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII Semester/Major-2/Applify'
```

Here 'Applify' is the git repository.

Using

```
ls -l /home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII\ Semester/Major-2/Applify
```

I found out the current ownership of the repository and it is the root user and the root group. So, I tried prefixing all git commands using sudo, and voila they were working.

Therefore, I tried to change the ownership by running:

```
sudo chown -R vrd:vrd /home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII\ Semester/Major-2/Applify
```

This also did not work. I am a bit new to the file structure and don't know in which directory to open the terminal and what should be the file path while running the commands. Tried a bunch of combinations, but they didn't work as well. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say: *This also did not work*. How do you know that it "did not work"? I'm asking because the `chown` command you are showing looks reasonable.

Comment: Because I verified the ownership again and it still showed the user and group both as 'root'.

Comment: Your `chown` command seems to be missing a backslash escape for the "VIII Semester" part.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. You meant sudo chown -R vrd:vrd /home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII\ Semester/Major-2/Applify

But that did not work as well.

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l /home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII\ Semester/Major-2` in your post?

Comment: Command:

vrd@Vinayaks-IdeaPad:~$ ls -l /home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII\ Semester/Major-2

Output: 
total 44

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Feb  5 22:45  Applify

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36352 Jan 10 19:07 'B.Tech. Weekly Meeting Schedule.doc'

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Feb  5 22:45 'Weekly Reports'

Comment: Thanks, but could you add that directly in your post, instead of the comments section? Code blocks don't work in comments.

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Feb 5 22:45 Applify` : therefore your `chown` attempt did not work. Please try a `chown -Rv vrd:vrd '/home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII Semester/Major-2'` (note the single quotes around the path) and update your post with its output.

Comment: Which directory should I be in while executing the above command. Like do I have to run a cd command before ?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are in the filesystem since we are supplying the `chown` command with **full path** to the target directory. You can run `sudo chown -Rv vrd:vrd '/home/vrd/Documents/JUET/VIII Semester/Major-2'` from anywhere.

Comment: Yes @Grobu the above command worked ! Now the ownership has been changed to VRD and there is no dubious ownership message anymore. Thank you for your help. However, could you tell me what I was doing wrong all this time ?

Comment: @VinayakRaoDikshit glad that it worked. I don't know why it didn't earlier though. It can be assumed that your command was missing a backslash escape(?). Statements like _"This also did not work"_ are not informational, better provide the raw command output. Also, it is advisable to execute commands in _verbose_ mode (like `chown -v ...`). One last thing, the root user account should be used sparingly. Don't `git clone` as root under `/home/vrd/...`!